# How to properly copy an executable byte by byte

Tags: copy, byte, fopen, filestream, fwrite

I have recently been trying to learn more about copying files via bytes, but I am having trouble. When checking the bytes from the original notepad.exe against notepad2.exe, even though the fread and frwite size is consistent across reading and writing I get different results.

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
FILE* file;
FILE* ofile;

file = fopen("notepad.exe", "rb");

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
long fSize = ftell(file);
rewind(file);

BYTE* ret = new BYTE[fSize];

fread(ret, 1, fSize, file);

fclose(file);

ofile = fopen("notepad2.exe", "w");
fwrite(ret, 1, fSize, ofile);

fclose(ofile);
```

I may be under the wrong assumption it even works like this, I am fairly new to working with lower level manipulation of memory. Thanks ahead for the help guys.

Comment: Gonna bump one time and let it die, let me know if anyone has a solution. original exe is 256kb rewritten one is 257kb and unopenable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download a free **hex editor** and visually check both files' bytes there. That will make it easier to see where things you went wrong.

Obviously you have some extra bytes (possibly many `00` values) but... is it at the front or the back of copied file bytes?

- Check value of `Fsize`, and length of `ret` (check before `fwrite`),
   are both matching your expected amounts?
- Instead of :`ofile = fopen("notepad2.exe", "w");`
  try setting as: 
  `ofile = fopen("notepad2.exe", "wb");`
- Use a `while` or `for` loop to **read** each single byte from `ret` and **write**/**append** the same value to byte in disk file (notepad2.exe).

Comment: Worked was not writing back in binary mode, easy miss thanks for the answer.